# UITabBar help, please no fix yet!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a TabBar with 2 viewControllers set to it, and a mainScreen view. What I want at application launch to display the *mainScreen view* w/ the TabBar at the bottom, and only switch to TabBars viewControllers once the TabBar is touched.

My problem is that the TabBars viewController's views will only be displayed, unless I set the views of the TabBar to clearColor, *only* then the mainScreen View is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you really should put your applicationDidFinishLaunching code here to help us understand your goal.

So, the idea is they can never get back to the "mainScreen view"?  It's a little odd, but I guess you could monitor the tabBar, and when they press it, you remove the mainScreen. So your main app delegate would look something like:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"tab pressed");
    [self.mainScreen removeFromSuperview]; 
    self.mainScreen = nil;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Build your tab controller here (or load in mainwindow.xib)
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

    //now build your mainScreen (or get from mainwindow); for example...
    self.mainScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480-49)];
    self.mainScreen.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    UIButton * temp = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(110, 60, 100, 20)];
    temp.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];    
    [mainScreen addSubview:temp];
    [temp release];

    //now put your mainscreen "over" your tabBar
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:mainScreen];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you. That worked perfectly. It is an odd program flow I know

Answer (score 1):

I think this means your mainScreen view is below your TabBar view in the hierarchy. You could add your "mainScreen" view as a subView of your initial tabBar view.

Once the user interacts with the tab bar you can simply remove your mainScreen view. In your tab bar delegate:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
   if ([viewController.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:@"TitleOfFirstViewInTabBar"]) {
       [mainScreenView removeFromSuperview]; // Assuming mainScreenView is available
   }
}
```